# Replacing text in a span in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following span

```
<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper">Search results for: 'soda'</span>
```

and i am trying to remove `Search results for` and replace with with some other text

This is the jquery

```
$(".base span").text(function(index, text) {

return text.replace('Search results for', 'We got you');

});
```

and this is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kcLuh0a1/1/

Why is the code not changing the text?

Comment: It's not `$(".base span")` it is `$("span.base")`

Comment: @VaraPrasad, Post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was that `.base span` was not found. Use `span.base` instead.

```
$("span.base").text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace('Search results for', 'We got you');
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3a98pde/

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you are finding a `span` element inside the element having class `base`

But you need to apply this for span so your code will be like this

```
$("span.base").text(function(index, text) {

return text.replace('Search results for', 'We got you');

});
```